# /joint_states from rviz with gazebo running

Tags: gazebo, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I would like to have the same robot running in gazebo and in rviz. I need the joint_states from rviz but I got the problem that gazebo is publishing them too. is there a way to filter the rviz-joint_states?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12356//joint_states-from-rviz-with-gazebo-running/) by [javatar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1540/javatar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rviz neither publishes nor subscribes to joint_states. It is just a visualization tool and the robot is visualized based on TF. Can you please provide more information on the display type you are using?

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at remapping arguments.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-12-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1